# Prove that $e-\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n}>{1 \over 2n}$ if $n \geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove, using only "basic" math (I think I am not even allowed to used logarithms, definitely not derivates. Basically only real sequences and their limits) that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(e-(1+{1 \over n})^n)$$
converges conditionally.
I have proved that the series converges by observing that it is decreasing to 0 and I am working on showing that $\sum |a_n|$ diverges. 
I think that  $e-(1+{1 \over n})^n > {1 \over 2n} $ if $n\geq 2$ which would imply that $\sum |a_n|$ diverges.The inequality holds for n=2,3,4 but I can't find a way to prove it. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Asymptotically $(1+\frac 1 n)^n=e^{n\log n}=e^{n(\frac 1 n-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(n^{-3}))}=e\big(1-\frac 1 {2n}+O(\frac 1 {n^2})\big)$ which proves divergence but doesn't answer your question.

Comment: It wasn't clear at first, but I edited the post: I can only use basic math.

Comment: How do you show that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing using "basic" math?

Comment: I guess the basic binomial expansion of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ works and the terms will cancel perfectly with the expansion of $e^1 = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + \dots$, the difference is $1/2n$ + positive terms

Comment: What kind of "basic" math do you use to define $e$?

Comment: e is defined as the limit of the sequence {$(1+{1 \over n})^n$}. You can show that the sequence is increasing by using the fact that if $0\leq a < b \rightarrow {b^{n+1}-a^{n+1} \over b-a}< (n+1)b^n$ and set $a=1+{1 \over n+1}$ and $b=1+{1 \over n}$

Comment: @Niebla if the answer is useful, please mark it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First term:

$$e^1 = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + \dots$$

Second term:

\begin{align*}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n &= 1 + n \cdot \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!} \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} \frac{1}{n^3} + \cdots \\
&= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) + \frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right) + \cdots
\end{align*}

subtracting the two, we get
$$\frac{1}{2n} + \text{positive}$$
for all $n \geq 2$, QED.

Comment: Just realized that the same trick can be used to show that: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left(e - \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \right) = \frac{1}{2}e$$

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1478502/43329)